# how to fix this Error Cannot use the same canvas during multiple render() operations

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I am using canvas in react and rendering pdf's as images using the canvas.

Now, when I get new data i.e another pdf get's added, then
again have to use the canvases for that.

I am not sure how to fix this error or how to remove the canvas or even clear the canvas before using it again.

Here's the relevant code:

```
 pdfLoop = (item,index) => {
        var that = this;
        PDFJS.getDocument(item).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
             //
             // Fetch the first page
             console.log('url is : ',item);
             pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
               var scale = 0.5;
               var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);


                   let cref = 'canvas'+index;
                   let imgref ='img'+index;
                   console.log('cref no : ',cref);
                   console.log('img no : ',imgref);

                   // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                   //
                   var canvas = that.canvasRefs[cref];
                   //let imagez = that.imageRefs[imgref];
                   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                   context.globalcompositeoperation = 'source-over';
                  // context.fillStyle = "#fff";
                  //draw on entire canvas
                  //context.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
                   canvas.height = viewport.height;
                   canvas.width = viewport.width;

                    //imagez.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                   //
                   // Render PDF page into canvas context
                   //
                   //page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});
                   var task = page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport})
              task.promise.then(function(){
                //console.log(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
                let imgItem = {imgref:canvas.toDataURL('image/png'),page:index+1,rotate:0}

                 let newState = that.state.imgsrc;
                 newState[index] = imgItem;
                 //let newState = that.state.imgsrc.concat(imgItem);
                that.setState({
                    imgsrc:newState
                });
                //imagez.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
              });

             });
           });
       }
```

Answer (score 6):

In case someone stumbles across this, the error message states the following `Use different canvas or ensure previous operations were cancelled or completed.`

When getting the document, if there already is a document, it has to be destroyed. I.e:

```
PDFJS.getDocument({ url: pdf_url }).promise
    .then((pdf_doc) => {

        if (this.pdf_doc) {
            this.pdf_doc.destroy();
        }
        this.pdf_doc = pdf_doc;
        this.total_pages = this.pdf_doc.numPages;
    })
```

I have no idea if this is a good solution, but at least it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same exact problem as you, but my solution was a bit different than the answers previously posted.

For me the problem was the fact that I was **unnecessarily re-rendering with a state change**. Check if you aren't re-rendering the component without properly clearing the canvas, or if you even need to re-render at all (in my case I didn't).

Hopefully this could help

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid this situation, put your canvas object in a div object as is shown below:

```
<div id="div_canvas">
    <canvas id="cnv"></canvas>
</div>
```

Then, before to call pdf.js functions, remove the "div_canvas" content and recreate it:

```
$("#div_canvas").html("");
$("#div_canvas").html("<canvas id='cnv'></canvas>");
```

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, this error will be displayed when the pdf has action buttons such as next/previous or scaling.
In this cases, often you have a function for rendering pdf page such as:

```
renderPage(num) {
    // Using promise to fetch the page
    pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function (page) {
        const viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        const renderContext = {
            canvasContext: ctx,
            viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    });
}
```

To fix the error just perform following changes:

1. Add two variable for controlling conflict and cache waiting page number:

   ```
   pageRendering = false; // Check conflict
   pageNumPending = null; // Cache waiting page number
   ```
2. Use these variables as follow:

   ```
   renderPage(num) {
     if (this.pageRendering) { // Check if other page is rendering
       this.pageNumPending = num; // Cache waited page number until previous page rendering completed
     } else {
       this.pageRendering = true;
       // Using promise to fetch the page
       pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function (page) {
           const viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
           canvas.height = viewport.height;
           canvas.width = viewport.width;

           // Render PDF page into canvas context
           const renderContext = {
               canvasContext: ctx,
               viewport: viewport
           };
           const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

           // Wait for rendering to finish
           renderTask.promise.then(function () {
               this.pageRendering = false;
               if (pageNumPending !== null) {
                   // Waited page must be rendered
                   this.renderPage(pageNumPending);
                   // Must be set to null to prevent infinite loop
                   this.pageNumPending = null;
               }
           });
       });
   ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it is also what is written in the documentation here: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue when working with **PDF.js**, the solution to this is,
You will have to clear your **context** after the render completes.

```
if (context) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
}
```

This will make sure that the context is cleared and ready for the next render and the error disappears.

this worked for me.

Comment: This did not solve it for me sadly. In my case it is trying to load another the same pdf again while the first time has not been done rendering. I guess I need to wait for the first process to be done or cancel it. How would you do either of those things?

Comment: Very late to the party. The object returned by `PDFJS.getDocument()`, which has the `promise` field, also has a `cancel` function. Call it, and it will cancel the current rendering and reject the `promise` object. You can then safely call `PDFJS.getDocument()` again.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause: React Strict mode renders twice